# Clearing innerHTML trouble in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

Here is my function:

```
    swPageProt.showContent = function () {
        if (this._Parent) {
            var container = this._Parent.getContentNode();
            if (container) {
                console.log(this._Content.innerHTML);
                console.log(this._Parent.getContentNode().innerHTML);
                container.innerHTML = '';
                if (this._Content instanceof WT.BaseControl) {
                    this._Content.addToNode(container);
                }
                else if (this._Content.tagName) {
                    console.log(this._Content.innerHTML);
                    console.log(this._Parent.getContentNode().innerHTML);
                    container.appendChild(this._Content);
                }
                else {
                    container.innerHTML = this._Content + '' || '';
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I want to clear parent container and append `this._Content` to it. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the line `container.innerHTML = '';` clears both parent and `this` instances in IE10. And I always get empty parent container with empty child (`this`) content. How to fix it in IE10?

Comment: What is `swPageProt`? What is `swPageProt._parent`? What does the related DOM look like? If `this._Content + ''` evaluates to false, how will the value be different to `''`?

Comment: @RobG, This `swPageProt` is user defined object. It represents page in pages stack. It has `_Content` property that represents HTML div element. It also has `_Parent` property, that represents the whole stack container. So  `this._Parent.getContentNode()` returns full stack container div element which also include `this._Content` as first child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!
It's necessary to use `container.removeChild(container.firstChild);` instead of `container.innerHTML = '';`